# Insert values from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

have two table. tbl1:

```
col1    col2    col3
A        A      Alex
```

and tbl2 :

```
id        name
 1         John
 2         Nen
 3         Bob
```

Want enter all names which is in tbl2 to the tbl1 col3, col1 and col2 must be former, for example i want like this :

```
  col1  col2    col3
    A        A      Alex
    A        A      John
    A        A      Nen
    A        A      Bob
```

I try something like this :

```
insert into tbl1(col1,col2,col3)
values('A','A',(select name from tbl2))
```

but have an error : **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try Like This...

```
insert into tbl1(col1,col2,col3)
Select 'A','A',name from tbl2
```

Comment: but how i can insert if name will be middle ? like this : Select 'A',name from tbl2,'A'

Comment: @GeoVIP try like this `insert into tbl1(col1,col2,col3)
Select 'A',name,'A' from tbl2`

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tbl1(col1,col2,col3) 
select 'A','A', name from tbl2
```